# Starting and monitoring spark application from a Java application

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-spark, executorservice

I am working on an application to execute `spark` batch application from a `java` application.

There is one main class which starts the thread to start `spark` application. It uses `zookeeper` to find the `leader` among machines which would start the `spark` application. `Main` method looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        final int id = Integer.valueOf(args[0]);
        final String zkURL = args[1];

        final ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

        final Future<?> status = service.submit(new ProcessNode(id, zkURL));
        try {
            status.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            LOG.fatal(e.getMessage(), e);
            service.shutdown();
        }
```

Once the `leader` is selected , following code would run on it to start `spark` application.

```
protected Boolean executeCommand() {
    try {
        final Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        final Process proc = rt.exec("sh start-sparkapp.sh");
        final int exitVal = proc.waitFor();
        BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
        String line = "";
        while ((line=buf.readLine())!=null) {
        System.out.println(line);
        }

        System.out.println(" commandToExecute exited with code: " + exitVal);
        proc.destroy();

    } catch (final Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception occurred while Launching process : " + e.getMessage());
        return Boolean.FALSE;
    }
         return Boolean.TRUE;
}
```

But this starts a long running `spark` job. So I believe, next part of code would be executed only when `spark` job is finished. My requirement is as soon as  `spark` application is started , the control goes to the next part of code, where I am monitoring the status of same `spark` application. i.e I start the `spark` application and monitor the status of `spark` application from same `java` application.
Assume I have a method `montior` which monitors the status of application

```
public String monitor(ApplicationId id)
```

Any suggestion how to achieve this?

Comment: Is the tag 'apache-spark' justified?

Answer (score 0):

Since you will be monitoring your Spark application using the method `public String monitor(ApplicationId id)` , I am assuming you do not want your current thread to wait on the process using `proc.waitFor()`. Additionally, you do not want to print the normal output of the process to your console. Both these operations make your thread wait on the spawned process. Moreover, your monitor method should take the process-id of the spawned process, rather than the spark applicationId, as input.
So the modified code could look like:

```
protected Boolean executeCommand() {
try {
    final Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    final Process proc = rt.exec("sh start-sparkapp.sh");

    /* 
     *Call to method monitor(ProcessId id)
     */

    } catch (final Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception occurred while Launching process : " + e.getMessage());
        return Boolean.FALSE;
    }
     return Boolean.TRUE;
}
```